# Nesting dictionaries in for loop

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, nested

Need to nest dictionaries to make a request. Can't figure how to add dictionary formed in for loop as value to new key in dictionary.

As result I need this structure:

```
dict["data']:
{
  passenger0 : {flight0 : {A}, flightM : {A}},
  passengerN : {flight0 : {Z}, flightM : {Z}}
}
```

As you can see, when I nest dictionary `A` to dictionary `B`, it works fine and I get structure I need.
But after I pass `B` to dictionary `C` same way as before, it doesn't take it as value for `"flight_id"` key. And values keep stacking through iteration.

Experimented with `copy`/`clear`, but didn't get proper result.

```
import copy
bags = 3
passengers = 2
flights_id = ["0000000", "1111111"]
A = B = C = D = A1 = B1 = C2 = D3 = {}

a = bags // passengers
b = bags % passengers

if passengers ==1:
  base_bag = [1] * (a-1)
  bag_long = base_bag + [1]
  bag_short = base_bag + [0]
else:
  base_bag = [1] * a
  bag_long = base_bag + [1]
  bag_short = base_bag + [0]

for p in range(passengers):
  for f in range(len(flights_id)):
    if p < b:
      A = dict(enumerate(bag_long, start=1))
    else:
      A = dict(enumerate(bag_short, start=1))
    print("This is A ", A)

    B[f'flight_id{f}'] = copy.deepcopy(A)
  print("This is B", B)
  C[f'passenger_id{p}'] = copy.deepcopy(B)
  print("This is C", C)
D["data"] = copy.deepcopy(C)
print("This is D", D)
```

Console output:

```
This is A  {1: 1, 2: 1}
This is A  {1: 1, 2: 1}
This is B {'flight_id0': {1: 1, 2: 1}, 'flight_id1': {1: 1, 2: 1}}
This is C {'flight_id0': {1: 1, 2: 1}, 'flight_id1': {1: 1, 2: 1}, 'passenger_id0':
    {'flight_id0': {1: 1, 2: 1}, 'flight_id1': {1: 1, 2: 1}}}
This is A  {1: 1, 2: 0}
This is A  {1: 1, 2: 0}
This is B {'flight_id0': {1: 1, 2: 0}, 'flight_id1': {1: 1, 2: 0}, 'passenger_id0':
    {'flight_id0': {1: 1, 2: 1}, 'flight_id1': {1: 1, 2: 1}}}
This is C {'flight_id0': {1: 1, 2: 0}, 'flight_id1': {1: 1, 2: 0}, 'passenger_id0':
    {'flight_id0': {1: 1, 2: 1}, 'flight_id1': {1: 1, 2: 1}}, 'passenger_id1': {'flight_id0':
    {1: 1, 2: 0}, 'flight_id1': {1: 1, 2: 0}, 'passenger_id0': {'flight_id0': {1: 1, 2: 1},
    'flight_id1': {1: 1, 2: 1}}}}
This is D {'flight_id0': {1: 1, 2: 0}, 'flight_id1': {1: 1, 2: 0}, 'passenger_id0':
    {'flight_id0': {1: 1, 2: 1}, 'flight_id1': {1: 1, 2: 1}}, 'passenger_id1': {'flight_id0':
    {1: 1, 2: 0}, 'flight_id1': {1: 1, 2: 0}, 'passenger_id0': {'flight_id0': {1: 1, 2: 1},
    'flight_id1': {1: 1, 2: 1}}}, 'data': {'flight_id0': {1: 1, 2: 0}, 'flight_id1': {1: 1, 2:
    0}, 'passenger_id0': {'flight_id0': {1: 1, 2: 1}, 'flight_id1': {1: 1, 2: 1}},
    'passenger_id1': {'flight_id0': {1: 1, 2: 0}, 'flight_id1': {1: 1, 2: 0}, 'passenger_id0':
    {'flight_id0': {1: 1, 2: 1}, 'flight_id1': {1: 1, 2: 1}}}}}
```

Comment: The first line of your code doesn't execute.  Should the commas be semi-colons?

Comment: Also, the second line raises an error.  Can you please check the code reproduces the result you want to ask about?

Comment: Also, I get `'bag_long' is not defined` and `'bag_short' is not defined`.

Comment: Additional code added

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dict` comprehensions like so:

```
bags = 3
passengers = 2 
flights_id = ["0000000", "1111111"] 

output = {"passenger" + str(i): {'flight' + str(j): idVal for j, idVal in enumerate(flights_id)} for i in range(passengers)}

print(output)
```

Output:

```
{'passenger0': {'flight0': '0000000', 
                'flight1': '1111111'}, 
 'passenger1': {'flight0': '0000000', 
                'flight1': '1111111'}}
```

If you want incorporate: `{1: 1, 2: 1}` like in your console output you will have to explain how that value is determined.

Additionally, your code is littered with errors. You will want to first address those before real issues with your approach can be determined.

Comment: Many thanks. Me so happy. With comprehension I managed to get dictionary I wanted. And  eventually made for-loop in first post work. Just needed to redefine A and B respectively at the beginning of loops. Like A = dict() etc.